# Need help converting Oracle trigger to Mariadb

Tags: oracle, triggers, mariadb, database-migration

I am new to mariadb trigger. I had this trigger in Oracle. Need help to convert it to mariadb:

```
    DECLARE 
    v_newVal NUMBER(12) := 0;
    v_incval NUMBER(12) := 0;
    BEGIN
      IF INSERTING AND :new.id IS NULL THEN
        SELECT  hvr_storyboards_id_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO v_newVal FROM DUAL;
        -- If this is the first time this table have been inserted into (sequence == 1)
        IF v_newVal = 1 THEN 
          --get the max indentity value from the table
          SELECT NVL(max(id),0) INTO v_newVal FROM hvr_storyboards;
          v_newVal := v_newVal + 1;
          --set the sequence to that value
          LOOP
               EXIT WHEN v_incval>=v_newVal;
               SELECT hvr_storyboards_id_SEQ.nextval INTO v_incval FROM dual;
          END LOOP;
        END IF;
        --used to emulate LAST_INSERT_ID()
        --mysql_utilities.identity := v_newVal; 
       -- assign the value from the sequence to emulate the identity column
       --:new.id := v_newVal;
      END IF;
    END;
```

I use a online conversion tool then manage to create it as

```
DECLARE 
v_newVal NUMBER(12) := 0;
v_incval NUMBER(12) := 0;
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING AND :new.id IS NULL THEN
    SELECT  hvr_storyboards_id_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO v_newVal FROM DUAL;
    -- If this is the first time this table have been inserted into (sequence == 1)
    IF v_newVal = 1 THEN 
      --get the max indentity value from the table
      SELECT NVL(max(id),0) INTO v_newVal FROM hvr_storyboards;
      v_newVal := v_newVal + 1;
      --set the sequence to that value
      LOOP
           EXIT WHEN v_incval>=v_newVal;
           SELECT hvr_storyboards_id_SEQ.nextval INTO v_incval FROM dual;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
    --used to emulate LAST_INSERT_ID()
    --mysql_utilities.identity := v_newVal; 
   -- assign the value from the sequence to emulate the identity column
   --:new.id := v_newVal;
  END IF;
END;
```

but I am getting this error

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO hvr_storyboards (name, updated_datetime, domain_id, ticker_id, updated_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["this is a test 6 - Ace", null, 21, null, null]: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'INSERTING' in 'field list'
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Whatever `online conversion tool` was used, is nowhere close to MariaDB's format in the converted output.

Comment: The functionality of the script is to do auto increment on a primary key. Is it similar to mariadb/mysql auto_increment ?

Comment: To me, it looks like the same code was posted twice, so is there some other code generated by the online conversion tool? ... MariaDB v10.3 [introduced sequences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequences/), if this may change anything that you're trying to do?

Comment: After some further checking , found out this codes is not needed. In Mysql can use auto_increment and sequence, which is simpler to use. Thanks for the suggestion Paul T.